# CompletableFuture and locks

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, guava, completable-future

I have the original synchronous code,

```
Lock lock = getLock(userId); // get a lock from guava Striped locks
lock.lock();

try {
   // do some database writing action
   updateUserByUserId(userId);
   return updateUserPropertiesByUserId(userId);
}
finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

The purpose of the lock is to mimic pessimistic database locking at a higher level.

In Java8, CompleteableFutures are introduced. And `updateUserByUserId(userId);` and `updateUserPropertiesByUserId(userId);` can now return `CompletableFuture<Void>` for a fully async implementation.

My question is, how can I employ the same mechanism? or is this way of locking completely wrong? (I don't really want to rely on the database's locking. If possible, I want to handle this in the app layer instead of the database layer)

I have tried

```
Lock lock = getLock(userId); // get a lock from guava Striped locks

return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> {
            lock.lock();
        })
        .thenCompose(VOID -> updateUserByUserId(userId))
        .thenCompose(entity -> updateUserPropertiesByUserId(userId))
        .whenComplete((entity, ex) -> {
            lock.unlock();
        });
```

But I've been getting `IllegalMonitorStateException` on `lock.unlock();`, which is expected, because you're not supposed to unlock a lock in a different thread.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your lock here is mimicking *pessimistic* locking, not optimistic. I don't see why you wouldn't rely on database transactions and locking instead though. Your locking mechanism will not work if you have several instances of your application running, or if someone else is accessing the same database.

Comment: You are right about calling the lock optimistic. I have changed it to say pessimistic.

This is a simple example to demonstrate what I am trying to do. In practice, my database has only 1 accessor, which is my microservice over only 1 interface. In an active-active setup, a lock retrieved from the caching layer is used instead. 

Why I'm trying to do this is because I want to "fail fast, fail early" instead of taking another hop to the database, which will throw an error, have the app tier convert the DB error to an exception and then catch that exception. It's quite a big hit.

Comment: And DB error conversion to Java exception can vary from DB to DB... Even different flavours of the same DB. I really don't want to handle that if possible.

Comment: There is no sense in splitting this linear operation into four stages, it’s still a sequence of directly dependent operations, you only made it more complicated and error prone, without any benefit. The two update methods would only be asynchronous when being called stand-alone, which would violate your locking requirement. In your `CompletableFuture` chain, you are waiting for the completion of each action before initiating the next one, as required, which makes the whole sequence as linear as before.

Comment: Ohh, makes sense! Let me revisit this

Answer (score 1):

You can supply an executor to the [`...Async` variants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenCompleteAsync-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) of the callbacks, so supplying the same [single threaded executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) to the one callbacks that lock and unlock should ensure they execute on the same thread.

```
Lock lock = getLock(userId); // get a lock from guava Striped locks
Executor lockExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> {
            lock.lock();
        }, lockExecutor)
        .thenCompose(VOID -> updateUserByUserId(userId))
        .thenCompose(entity -> updateUserPropertiesByUserId(userId))
        .whenCompleteAsync((entity, ex) -> {
            lock.unlock();
        }, lockExecutor);
```

**NOTE:** I haven't run this, hopefully it works!

Comment: I think the intention of the author was quite opposite: to spread execution on several threads

Comment: I believe this will spread execution on several thread. It only uses the same thread for the lock operations.. As the author hasn't been back in almost a year, I doubt we will ever know for sure if this answer was suitable.